# Sonarqube deleted local user cannot login anymore with remote ldap authentication

Tags: ldap, sonarqube

i am having some issue with sonarqube 5.6 LTS using LDAP authentication on a AD server.

Before finally managing to configure SQ to work with AD for ldap authentication i had created an user with a login name equal to an AD account.

Then i found out that i could set up in sonar.properties the property sonar.authenticator.createUser=true. So i clicked on the red cross (with a tooltip deactivate) on the user list to remove the the local user created by me so that the user could login via AD authentication.

Unfortunately it seems that SQ does not perform at all any query for the deleted local user. What can i do? (renaming the user account on the AD side is not an option)

thanks

Comment: Did you have a look in the SonarQube logs; any errors?

Comment: Nope, no error whatsoever, and does not show any ldap query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting SonarQube 5.6 `sonar.authenticator.createUser` is indeed not working anymore (see https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8208 for details).

Then you have 2 options :

- Upgrade to SonarQube 6.3 or later version, everything will work fine.
- Execute the following SQL request : `update users set user_local=false where login = '<LOGIN_TO_LOG_WITH_AD>'`